# Python/Pandas: Select specific value and return series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df that contains an ‘age_bracket’ in the form of 20-25, 25-30 etc.. and ’no_show’ which only has the values 0 or 1 for indicating if a patient showed up for an appointment or not.

For creating a bar chart, I need total and proportional values for show vs no show per age.
I tried this:

```
noshow_counts = df.groupby('age_bracket')['no_Show'].value_counts()[1]
show_counts = df.groupby('age_bracket')['no_Show'].value_counts()[0]
age_totals = df.groupby('age_bracket').count()['no_Show']
```

Calculating proportions like this

```
nowshow_proportions = noshow_counts / age_totals
show_proportions = show_counts /age_totals
```

And here is how it gets used in the bar chart

```
#Bar Chart
ind = np.arange(len(nowshow_proportions))  
width = 0.40 
# plot bars
noshow_bars = plt.bar(ind, nowshow_proportions, width, color='g', 
alpha=.7, label='No Show')
show_bar = plt.bar(ind + width, show_proportions, width, color='b', 
alpha=.7, label='Show')
```

This does not product the correct values. I am guessing this is because value_counts returns an object and not a series. So this is incorrect

```
 noshow_counts = df.groupby('age_bracket')['no_Show'].value_counts()[1]
 show_counts = df.groupby('age_bracket')['no_Show'].value_counts()[0]
```

Is there a way to select  only ‘1’ and only ‘0’ values and return a series?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? And how should the values be normalised? Across age groups or across show/no-show?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the correct result with

```
show_counts = df[df['no_Show'] == 0].groupby('age_bracket').count(). 
['no_Show']
noshow_counts=df[df['no_Show'] == 1].groupby('age_bracket').count(). 
['no_Show']
```